# Change MongoDB find results dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose with node.js.

Let's say I have 'Posts' DB where each document in it is a post.
Each post has a 'ReadBy' array which holds names of users that had read this post.

When I'm searching for documents in this DB, I want to "change" the 'ReadBy' value to show by Boolean value if the user that is searching for it is in this array or not.

For example, let's say these are 2 documents that are in this DB:

```
{ "PostName": "Post Number 1", "ReadBy": ["Tom", "John", "Adam"] }
{ "PostName": "Post Number 2", "ReadBy": ["John", "Adam"] }
```

If I'm user 'Tom', I want to get the results like this:

```
[
    {
        "PostName": "Post Number 1",
        "ReadBy": true,
    },
    {
        "PostName": "Post Number 2",
        "ReadBy": false,
    }
]
```

Now, I know that I can get the documents and go over each one of them with forEach function, and then use forEach again on the "ReadBy" array and change this field.

I'm asking if there is more efficient way to do it in the mongoDB query itself, or some other way in the code.

If there is another way with mongoose - even better.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/

Comment: Yes, I saw this. But in order to use it, I need to use $in operator. But it's not part of the aggregation framework as you can see here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576948/query-mongodb-array-and-sort-with-the-most-matched-elements/12577865#12577865

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using mongoDb **[$setIntersection](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/)** in `aggregation` you get the result like this :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
"$project": {
    "ReadBy": {
        "$cond": {
            "if": {
                "$eq": [{
                        "$setIntersection": ["$ReadBy", ["Tom"]]
                    },
                    ["Tom"]
                ]
            },
            "then": true,
            "else": false
        }
    },
    "PostName": 1
}
})
```

So above working first like this

```
{ $setIntersection: [ [ "Tom", "John", "Adam"], [ "Tom"] ] },  return [ "Tom"]

{ $setIntersection: [ [ "John", "Adam"], [ "Tom"] ] },  return [ ]
```

and [$eq](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) to check whether `setIntersection` results matched with `["Tom"]` if yes then return `true` else `false`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something similar to

```
var unwind = {"$unwind": "$ReadBy"}
var eq = {$eq: ["$ReadBy", "Bob"]}
var project = {$project: {PostName: 1, seen: eq}}
db.posts.aggregate([unwind, project])
```

Just notice that you solution is highly inefficient. Both for storing the data ( growing array) and for searching.